# When using getDerivedStateFromProps (React) getting error: Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

So just learned that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and we need to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method now.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

I'm using it as such below:

```
class Main extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps', props);
    const { modal } = props;
    this.setState({ modal });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modal: {}
    };
  }
```

However it errors out on the `setState`

[image]

> main.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
>       at getDerivedStateFromProps (main.js:30)

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might be able to use `componentWillMount` to check if there's a modal prop. If there is, set the state with it before it mounts. Rusty on react but I know using `componentDidMount` will throw an infinite loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a `static` function, there is no instance (`this`).

Instead, this function is designed so that you return your state rather than using `this.setState`.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps', props);
    const { modal } = props;
    return { modal };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah this was it, ok new bug... for some reason my Redux action/reducers aren't forcing this new method to fire. May post a new question about that later.

Comment: So, how can I access `this` in `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`?

Comment: I think it's important to note **an implementation like this is unnecessary**. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50784891/458193) for more details. (I work on React.)

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the mistake that was already pointed out (you need to return state), your implementation is buggy and won't work correctly.

You are trying to "sync" a prop into the local state. This is a bad idea because **any unrelated re-render of a parent component will destroy local state**.

It looks like you should completely remove `getDerivedStateFromProps`, and just use props directly. You don't need local state in this example at all.

For a more in-depth take on **why this pattern is broken, and some easy alternatives to it, check out [the official React blog post on avoiding deriving state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan! I'm honored :D And ok yeah I just removed that from my app, and yeah everything is working just from `this.props` so I guess the use case for `getDerivedStateFromProps` are some rare edge cases?

Comment: Yes, it's for rare cases when your state depends on a *change* in props. For example, `isScrollingDown` might depend on change in `scrollPosition`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using this in the context of a static method. Static does not rely on an instance of the class, so the this isn't the same. You're best bet is to return modal in a non static method and then set it from there :D

```js
class Main extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps', props);
    const { modal } = props;
    return modal;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modal: {}
    };
    
    SetModalState(modal)
    {
      this.setState(modal)
    }
  }
```